# How not to use ObjectManager in phtml from template

Tags: magento2, phtml, object-manager

First a bit of context, and at the end, my question

---

I added an EAV attribute to my customer. It's an attribute with multiple values, and I want to add it to the account information (for reasons).

I've made a module, added a source for my select element, observer, etc...

It's working ok.

Let's say it's in

`app/code/MyCompany/MyEAVAttributeModule`

I've got a custom theme, made by another team, in

`app/design/frontend/ThemeTeam/ThemeInUse`

To add my attribute to the register and edit form, I've added on the custom theme

`app/design/frontend/ThemeTeam/ThemeInUse/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml`

and

`app/design/frontend/ThemeTeam/ThemeInUse/Magento_Customer/templates/form/edit.phtml`

which are copies from

`/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` and `edit.phtml`

And to get all my values to add a select element, I've added in the phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$my_attributes = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config')->getAttribute('customer', 'my_attribute');

if ($my_attributes->getSource()) {
    $my_attribute_list = $my_attributes->getSource()->getAllOptions();
}
```

and then a `<select>` and a `foreach`

It works, my attribute is shown, the value is saved.

---

Now, for my question :-)

To get all the values, I get an instance of `ObjectManager` at the begining of my `phtml`

I know it's wrong to do that, but I couldn't find another way.

So how to do it ?

I know I should make a function and use a Helper (which I read is not recommended) or perhaps use it in the Block ?

But where ? In the theme ? In my module ? Somewhere else ?

Thanks if you can guide me on this one !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a view model and inject it via DI. You can access the view model instance from within the template.

customer_account_edit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Package\ViewModel\YourEavAttribute</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

EavAttribute.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * YourEavAttribute.php
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Package\ViewModel;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class YourEavAttribute implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /** @property Config $config */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @param Config $config
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $config
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * @return Config
     */
    public function getConfig(): Config
    {
        return $this->config;
    }
}
```

From inside your template:

```
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$config = $viewModel->getConfig();
```

Comment: Thanks ! It was not what I had in mind first (I wanted a way to get an instance of ObjectManager in my phtml), but your answer is way better and clean. And it helped me understand more how all this stuff work. Kudos !